# What is use of %S (uppercase s) in printf()?

Tags: c

I know the usage of `%s` (lowercase s) in `printf()` function of C. Recently I found `%S` (CAPITAL S) used in `printf()`. Can someone explain its usage. I can't find any information regarding this on internet.

Answer (score 10):

An [old, non-standard modifier](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> **`S`**
>
> (Not in C99, but in SUSv2.) Synonym for **`ls`**. Don't use.

`ls` (and therefore `S`) means to take a `const wchar_t *` instead of a `const char *` like `s`.

SUSv2 is the [The Single UNIX Specification, Version 2](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/).

Comment: Just to add to that, '%ls' expects an argument of type `wchar_t*`, and is rarely used because of a failure to agree on what `wchar_t` means (some implementations say it's a 16-bit word containing one Unicode UCS2-coded value; others say it's a 32-bit word containing a Unicode codepoint)

Comment: @KrisW +100 Wide characters are effectively deprecated, one should use UTF-8 instead. Even Microsoft (!) recommends nowadays doing so and re-encoding to UTF-16 at the edge of their API. One can dream about C# and Java moving to UTF-8 too :')